# ionicframework/angularjs: ios error: Attempted to assign to readonly property

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, restangular

Hi all I have this code :

```
RestangularProvider.setResponseExtractor(function(response) {
            var newResponse = response;
            newResponse.originalElement = response;   //THIS IS LINE 112
            return newResponse;
        });
```

In Android all OK, but in IOS (Xcode console) I get this:

```
ERROR: Error: Attempted to assign to readonly property.
file:///var/mobile/Applications/0799BB3F-DEF2-4BC6-A360-6D31BE7AFB43/Utrend.app/www/scripts/app.js:112:24
```

Where is my error ?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to look into this issue in guthub. Looks like some people have a patch available https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9128